# How to request procurement from one warehouse to another in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Using Odoo `saas-14`, I would like to use the "Request Procurement" button on the product form to trigger the transfer of products from WH2 to WH1, but I'm having trouble finding the proper way to do this. My intention was to request the procurement to WH1, and select a newly created route called WH2->WH1. That route should contain a Procurement Rule that creates a Delivery Order from WH2 to a Transit Location. When that Delivery Order is confirmed, a push rule on the route would tell the system to then create a receipt for WH1 from the Transit Location to Stock.

However, from what I have found so far, it seems like this is not possible. When creating the procurement rule, a Procurement Location has to be set. This needs to be set to WH1, the ultimate destination of the products, in order for the procurement to use the created rule. Setting this procurement location to WH1 results in the created picking (the Delivery Order from WH2) to always have a destination location of WH1, even though I actually want it to go to the Transit location.

Isn't there some way in the system to define a route that says "when products need to be routed from here to here, follow these steps"? From my experience so far it's not possible because the rules procurement location field always dictates the destination of the created picking, so there is no way to have any intermediate steps? Is this true? Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it based on configuration process.

In **Inventory >> Warehouse >> Technical Information** you will find option for default **Resupply Warehouse**.

When you set resupply warehouse and save it system will automatic create routes.

ex : If you have two warehouses wh1 and wh2 and you want to send stock from wh1 warehouse to wh2 warehouse, then you need to set wh1 warehouse as resupply in wh2 warehouse.

> **You can also configure multiple resupply warehouses.**

[image: Configuration]

> Inventory >> Configuration >> Settings you need to configure Advanced
>   routing of products using rules

[image]

There is one app available in odoo store to manage all this scenario easily. These two are main features of this app.

- [Inter Company Transfer](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/intercompany_transaction_ept/)
- [Inter Warehouse Transfer](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/intercompany_transaction_ept/)

Comment: Thank you, that was a huge help. I didn't realize that the resupply functionality creates routes for you automatically. None of the documentation, webinars, or my functional consultant told me that. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Follow-up question here...I see that the resupply route automatically creates a delivery order and a linked receipt. However, where does the address of the final destination warehouse come into play? In other words, the delivery order from the resupply warehouse does not contain any information about where the shipment is going. It just has a destination location of transit, but doesn't say anything about the warehouse where the shipment is going. Is that intentional? How is the resupply warehouse supposed to know where to ship products to?